# JPOS: Using pure java code vs Q2 to simulate acquirer and issuer?

Tags: jpos

currently I'm using jPOS to connect to our switch (payment gateway?), simulating both the acquirer and issuer. In other words, jPOS (client) will connect to the acq port on the switch (server), pack and send the iso message, switch routes it to the issuer port, which jPOS is also connected as a client, receives the request, packs and sends a response back to the switch.

I hope the above makes sense. I do have java code in place, but as it gets more complicated I've been considering using Q2 instead, but after reading through all of the Q2 documentation, I'm still unsure on a few things.

1. Firstly, my program will receive an HTTP POST request with all of the PORT, IP, and Transaction details. It won't know what the port is until it receives that data, so how can I create Q2 Channel-adapters, qservers, etc dynamically? Don't those files need to be predefined in the deploy folder? There will also be N number of these connections.
2. I would like to be able to have the issuer side open and waiting to respond automatically for any transaction, but also have the ability to modify the response for specific txns. Can that be achieved?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I would suggest breaking your question in two different separate SO questions, since the 1 and 2 are two different things that can (and should) be addressed separately.

Comment: Regarding the 1, I don't believe what you are trying to achieve is possible with existing components, you would have to implement your own `DynamicChannel`, probably based on https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/blob/master/jpos/src/main/java/org/jpos/q2/iso/OneShotChannelAdaptor.java, but it wouldn't be a `Channel` unless you encode the ip and port in the message header or in a private field.

Comment: One other thing you could do if you don't have control over the client that performs the HTTP request,and if you know in advance all the ips and ports, is to have some kind of map from ip+port to some channel name, and have one channel for each. You could implement that mapping in one transaction participant if you use a transaction manager or (not recommended for producton, but could save some logic) in the request listener itself.

Comment: Regarding 2, you can use the [ServerSimulator jPOS-EE module](https://github.com/jpos/jPOS-EE/blob/master/doc/src/asciidoc/module_server_simulator.adoc)

Comment: Thank you. yes I should split this into two separate questions. I'll take a look at your comments and see if I can't come up with anything. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, I suggested breaking this question in 2, but meanwhile I'll answer the easy one (the number 2).

For this, you can use the [ServerSimulator jPOS-EE module](https://github.com/jpos/jPOS-EE/blob/master/doc/src/asciidoc/module_server_simulator.adoc) (see section 10.2 of [jPOS-EE manual](http://jpos.org/doc/jPOS-EE.pdf)).

You can see an example configuration at https://github.com/jpos/jPOS-EE/tree/master/modules/server-simulator/src/main/resources/META-INF/q2/installs.